# Javascript event handler (mouseover) not firing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bind, mouseover

I have a homepage that dynamically writes javascript in order to handle the mouseover of potential user choices. However, the .bind("mouseover",function()) does not seem to be working.

The PHP produces a script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function setPreview(art, title, rt, excerpt) {
     $("#boxPreview").attr("src", art);
     $("#selectedTitle").text(title);
     $("#runningTime").text(rt);
     $("#excerpt").text(excerpt);
   }

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#tb0").bind("mouseover",setPreview(url,title,running time,excerpt));
     $("#tb1").bind("mouseover",setPreview(url,title,running time,excerpt));
     $("#tb2").bind("mouseover",setPreview(url,title,running time,excerpt));
     $("#tb3").bind("mouseover",setPreview(url,title,running time,excerpt));
</script>
```

However, it seems that the mouseover event never fires. Instead, it seems that when the page is fully loaded, setPreview is run for the very last element (#tb3).

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. If you would like to see the page in action for yourself, you can view it [here](http://videogamecinema.com/home-testbed/).

Comment: use .on() instead of .bind()

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to really change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try writing the same code like this

$("#tb0").bind("mouseover" , function(){

```
    setPreview(url,title,running time,excerpt);
```

});

This may solve your issue. Because i've got same issue before but it was fixed writing this way.